# Record screen for google's RL football simulator

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm trying to record the screen while simulating a football game with [google's football simulator](https://github.com/google-research/football) which is based on [openAI-Gym](https://gym.openai.com/). My code currently is:

```
import gfootball.env as football_env

env = football_env.create_environment(env_name='11_vs_11_stochastic', render=True)
env.reset()
done = False
while not done:
    action = env.action_space.sample()
    observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
```

which shows the game but I have no clue how to record it.
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to use Python for screen recording? Then you could try to run this code is separate process - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-a-screen-recorder-using-python/.

Comment: I think openAI-gym has a built-in function for recording the screen. I'm hoping to find a way to use that method since it will be much more efficient. But I might have to consider using python like you mentioned if that doesn't work. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is wondering, there's a good documentation [here](https://github.com/google-research/football/blob/master/gfootball/doc/saving_replays.md). All you need to do is add `write_video = True` to the environment configs.
My code now looks like this and works:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

from absl import app
from absl import flags
from absl import logging


from gfootball.env import config
from gfootball.env import football_env

FLAGS = flags.FLAGS

flags.DEFINE_string('players', 'keyboard:left_players=1',
                    'Semicolon separated list of players, single keyboard '
                    'player on the left by default')
flags.DEFINE_string('level', '', 'Level to play')
flags.DEFINE_enum('action_set', 'default', ['default', 'full'], 'Action set')
flags.DEFINE_bool('real_time', True,
                  'If true, environment will slow down so humans can play.')
flags.DEFINE_bool('render', True, 'Whether to do game rendering.')


def main(_):
  players = FLAGS.players.split(';') if FLAGS.players else ''
  assert not (any(['agent' in player for player in players])
             ), ('Player type \'agent\' can not be used with play_game.')
  cfg = config.Config({
      'action_set': FLAGS.action_set,
      'dump_full_episodes': True,
      'players': players,
      'real_time': FLAGS.real_time,
      'dump_full_episodes': True,
      'tracesdir': 'path/to/dir',
      'write_video': True,
      'render': True
  })
  if FLAGS.level:
    cfg['level'] = FLAGS.level
  env = football_env.FootballEnv(cfg)
  if FLAGS.render:
    env.render()
  env.reset()
  try:
    while True:
      _, _, done, _ = env.step([])
      if done:
        env.reset()
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    logging.warning('Game stopped, writing dump...')
    env.write_dump('shutdown')
    exit(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(main)
```

Note that I've just added some configs to the [file in official github repo](https://github.com/google-research/football/blob/master/gfootball/play_game.py).